42Crunch conformance scan issue
I have implemented OpenAPI for the first time for my SpringBoot project.
I am stuck with these errors as I don't find documents or solutions anywhere.
It would be great if someone could direct me to the right document or provide the solution.

Error for API1
1. The response is not valid: The body of the received response is not valid against the schema constraining it in the OpenAPI definition : path / value is not a string, got []interface {} '[string1 string2 string3]'

Reason for the Above: I convert a list into JSON string using ObjectMapper and then return as ResponseEntity

Errors for API 2

The API accepts a request with an unexpected data type (object)
instead of 'number'
The API accepts a generated value smaller than
the minimum defined for it
The API accepts a property value greater than the allowed maximum for an integer or number
The API accepts a request with an unexpected data type (object) instead of 'string'


Resolved the 1st one:
Instead of converting a list to a JSON String. We have created a model class and set the model as a return type. So, now the Swagger will pass this test.
Yet to fix the issues in the 2nd API

For API 2, the errors indicate the API is not behaving as expected, or as documented in your OpenAPI contract.
By constraining, or whitelisting, the API input you can limit the malicious input a hacker can try on the API to find and exploit a vulnerability. It also helps valid API consumers to use the API correctly.
The solution is to enforce the constraints in your API code, so that it:

rejects invalid data types if the property is required to be a number
rejects values that are out of bounds (e.g. below the minimum you've set)
rejects values that are out of bounds (e.g. above the maximum you've set)
rejects invalid data types if the property is required to be a string

On your question about where to find the documentation, see developers.42crunch.com for details.
